# Updating CI view data through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, codeigniter

I was happily coding, thinking I'd not run into problems anymore (for now, at least), until I came to the AJAX part of my application.

First, a bit of background. I'm working on a calendar/planner app. My controller loads data (a rather complex array) from a model and passes it to a view in my index() function. All good till there. 
Now, I want to update my data through ajax. I'm showing a bunch of dates, and when the user clicks on the 'previous' or 'next' buttons, I want to show the previous/next month.

I've been able to do this in the past with super-messy and plain bad code. I rewrote my code from scratch now, but now I'm stuck. I have an AJAX call to the following function:

```
    public function change_dates()
{
    $month = $this->input->post('month');
    $year = $this->input->post('year');
    $dates = $this->planner_model->create_date_list($month, $year);

    // echo $dates back to ajax? :(
}
```

I take the post values, send them to my model, save the data in an array and then I'm stuck. Because the data array is complex, I have a foreach loop, among other things, in my view. If I just echo it back to my view's ajax call, I can't really do anything with it. It's not like I can use `.html()` here to get my data in my view. I need a way to update the whole array in my view with the new values, if that makes sense? I tried stuff like `$this->load->vars()` but I'm a bit of a newbie and I don't even know if that's the right way of doing this, haha.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The easy, reliable way:

Make sure your page uses `$this->load->view()` to load a view fragment (the html that creates the calendar) separately from your header, footer, etc.

When you make the AJAX call to `change_dates()`, have it do it's thing, then load **only** that view file, passing the new data with `$this->load->vars()` or `$this->load->view('calendar', $data)`. If you need to only load the view if it is an AJAX request, just detect the AJAX call:

```
public function change_dates()
{
    $month = $this->input->post('month');
    $year = $this->input->post('year');
    $dates = $this->planner_model->create_date_list($month, $year);

    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) // Available as of CI 2.0
    {
        $data['dates'] = $dates;
        $this->load->view('calendar', $data);
        // You may need to load other data here, If so, consider a common function that
        // can be shared with your main view to render the calendar
    }
}
```

In your jQuery, you will be expecting html as a return value. Simply take the value and load it into your div or wherever the calendar is shown with the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jQuery functions. You're basically just reloading the entire thing, which ensures you are getting the correct output.

```
$.get(url, function(response) {
    $('#main_content').html(response);
}, 'html');// will usually use auto detection

// Or when you KNOW you're expecting HTML

$('#main_content').load(url);

// Or without the ajax detect (slower, less recommended)

$('#main_content').load(url + ' #main_content');
```

---

#### The precise, difficult way:

Use above methods, but echo/exit [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the data into whatever form you need, then make sure to expect a json return value from your jQuery. You will now get an array that you can manipulate the document with however you choose.

---

If you are on an older version than 2.0 - [It's time to upgrade](http://codeigniter.com/)!, but here is the function they use for ajax detection (not much to it):

```
public function is_ajax_request()
{
    return ($this->server('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') === 'XMLHttpRequest');
}
```

Comment: Thanks; that worked. Only problem is that I can't do my nice fadeIn() effect with jQuery anymore now since it'll fade in the whole div. Oh well. It's fine as it is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just do a hide() first, then fadeIn() when you get your data, it's easy!

Comment: Ya, but it's ugly when I fadeIn() the whole div since it has a background and such ;) I have a list in it, which I used to do a fade effect on, but now I'm working on 'div level'.  Unless I set the list to display: none and fade it in after getting my data?

Comment: Updated answer with the other method :) You can really do a number of tricks to simulate only parts of the page reloading with method 1, but this would be detailed code and I haven't seen your page.

Comment: I put the list I want to fade in to display:none and I'm just making it fade in after I loaded the new data with .html(). It looks just like I wanted it now. Thanks for your time!